# Java PreparedStatement use issue

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

I have an issue which I am unable to resolve having tried multiple times to do as much as possible.

I have a table `X` with the following structure (due to Column drop and create):

```
A  String
B  Int
D  Int
C  Boolean
G  Boolean
E  Int
F  Boolean
```

I am preparing a preparedStatement to try and insert the data into the above columns

```
for (I=0 ; I < 5 ; I++) {
    pS = INSERT IN X (A, B, D, C, E ) Values (?,?,?,?,?);
    //Observer the query.

    pS.SetString (1,a);
    pS.SetString (2,100);
    pS.SetString (3,100);
    pS.SetString (4,0);
    pS.SetString (5,200);

    ps.AddBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

However I get an Error

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "G" (actual: 3, maximum: 1)

Even though I wouldn't want to enter anything in the column G as per the query why does it try to insert into column G.

Comment: May be set default `o` for Boolean field .

Comment: Post the DDL of the table (`create table` statement). `BOOLEAN` is not a valid Oracle type. Possible exaplanation, you habe a `VARCHAR2(1)`column and a trigger trying to insert `'YES'`;)

Comment: is column G nullable?

Comment: Yes Column G is nullable. Also the column is VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)

Comment: The issue isn't about the column what I see the issue is though my query doesn't refer to column G but because Column G is column 5 and pS.SetString (5,200); is trying to insert into column 5 ???? That's my hypothesis.

Comment: you can't use ps.setString() to insert integer values,use ps.setInt()

Answer (score 0):

G is not inserted, in your code; should have a default in the DDL.
For a boolean use setBoolean or setInt.

```
// Column G  Boolean DEFAULT '0'

try (PreparedStatement pS = con.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT IN X (A, B, D, C, E) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    for (int I = 0; I < 5; I++) {
        pS.SetString(1, a);
        pS.SetInt(2, 100);
        pS.SetInt(3, 100);
        pS.SetBoolean(4, false);
        pS.SetInt(5, 200);

        pS.AddBatch();
    }
    pS.executeBatch();
}
```

Comment: Even with the above setup the error is still the same. As I explained previously what I see is happening that pS.SetInt(5, 200) does the 5 in this statement mean column 5 in the table. Does it mean 5th element of the query?

Comment: The fifth `?`, E, with is an `INT(3 or more)`, not a boolean `INT(1)`. Maybe the error stems from 200 having 3 digits.

Comment: And A, B, D, C, E are column names as defined (G suspiciously missing).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use all the table keys and simply set the values you want

as if it had five elements, now you have seven you use a set of seven elements

```
for (I=0 ; I < 5 ; I++) {
    pS = INSERT IN X (A, B, C,D, E,F,G ) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
    //Observer the query.

    pS.SetString (1,a);
    pS.SetString (2,100);
    pS.SetString (3,100);
    pS.SetString (4,0);
    pS.SetString (5,200);
    pS.SetString (6,200);
    pS.SetString (7,200);

    ps.AddBatch();
}
ps.executeBatch();
```

Comment: I may not want to insert data in some columns based on the certain criteria. Therefore it will not be sensible to add data in all columns. That is why the columns could be nullable.

Comment: You can use setString to null for the values you want to be nullable

Comment: My issue isn't setting the string to NULL or not the issue is the order of the insert of this data. Does the preparedStatement expect that I have to insert the data into all columns as part of the AddBatch? OR can I skip columns